# MVC4 Validation DataAnnotations not working (not validating)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a pretty complex model and a view (below).  I only have ONE of my fields as Required (Key Active Mg).  When I mark this `[Required(ErrorMessage="Key Active Mg is required")]` and set the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` for that field, my app will let me enter nothing and click Save.  Of course, `Model.IsValid` will return `false`.  It doesn't come back and outline the field in red indicating it's required.  Does anyone know why?

My model:

```
    public class RawValues
    {
        [Key]
        public int Pk { get; set; }

        public int? FillerFk { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Filler")]
        [ForeignKey("FillerFk")]
        public virtual Filler Filler { get; set; }

        public int? CapsuleFk { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Capsule")]
        [ForeignKey("CapsuleFk")]
        public virtual Capsule Capsule { get; set; }

        public int? KeyActiveFk { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Key Active")]
        [ForeignKey("KeyActiveFk")]
        public virtual KeyActive KeyActive { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="API #1")]
        public int? Active1 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "API #2")]
        public int? Active2 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "API #3")]
        public int? Active3 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "API #4")]
        public int? Active4 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "API #5")]
        public int? Active5 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Key Active Mg")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Key Active Mg is required.")]
        public int KeyActiveMg { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "E4M")]
        public bool E4M { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "K100M")]
        public bool K100M { get; set; }

        public int TimeReleaseFillerFk { get; set; }
        public int NumberCapsules { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

My View:

```
@model CapWorx.QuikCap.Models.RawValues

@* This partial view defines form fields that will appear when creating and editing entities *@

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Capsule, new { @class = "ui-input-text" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Capsule.Pk, new SelectList(ViewBag.Capsules, "Pk", "Name", "Pk"))
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active1)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active1)
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active2)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active2)
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active3)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active3)
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active4)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active4)
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active5)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active5)
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KeyActive, new { @class = "ui-input-text" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.KeyActive.Pk, new SelectList(ViewBag.KeyActives, "Pk", "Name", "Pk"))
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KeyActiveMg)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KeyActiveMg)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KeyActiveMg)
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.E4M)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.E4M,
                              new[] { 
                                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Off", Value = "False", Selected = true }, 
                                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "On", Value = "True" } },
                              new { data_role = "slider" })
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.K100M)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.K100M,
                              new[] { 
                                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Off", Value = "False", Selected = true }, 
                                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "On", Value = "True" } },
                              new { data_role = "slider" })
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Filler, new { @class = "ui-input-text" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filler.Pk, new SelectList(ViewBag.Fillers, "Pk", "Name", "Pk"))
    @Html.ValidationMessage("FillerName", "Filler is required")
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(RawValues rawvalues)
        {
            rawvalues.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            rawvalues.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            rawvalues.TimeReleaseFillerFk = Helpers.OperationContext.GetTimeReleaseFillerFk(rawvalues.E4M, rawvalues.K100M);

            rawvalues.CapsuleFk = rawvalues.Capsule.Pk;
            rawvalues.FillerFk = rawvalues.Filler.Pk;
            rawvalues.KeyActiveFk = rawvalues.KeyActive.Pk;

            rawvalues.Filler = Helpers.OperationContext.GetFiller(rawvalues.Filler.Pk);
            rawvalues.Capsule = Helpers.OperationContext.GetCapsule(rawvalues.Capsule.Pk);
            rawvalues.KeyActive = Helpers.OperationContext.GetKeyActive(rawvalues.KeyActive.Pk);

            rawvalues.NumberCapsules = 100;

            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                rawvaluesRepository.InsertOrUpdate(rawvalues);
                rawvaluesRepository.Save();
                List<Results> results = Helpers.OperationContext.CallCalculate(rawvalues);
                return View("Results", results);
            } else {
                ViewBag.Error = "Model State was not valid.";
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

My screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've updated my controller code to be the following:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        rawvaluesRepository.InsertOrUpdate(rawvalues);
        rawvaluesRepository.Save();
        List<Results> results = Helpers.OperationContext.CallCalculate(rawvalues);
        return View("Results", results);
    } else {
        ViewBag.Capsules = Helpers.OperationContext.GetCapsules();
        ViewBag.Fillers = Helpers.OperationContext.GetFillers();
        ViewBag.KeyActives = Helpers.OperationContext.GetKeyActives();
        return View();
    }
```

This resolves my issue.  I needed to return the same View to display the errors on the screen.  With DataAnnotations Validation, the form does in fact hit the HttpPost method of Create, and if there are errors (validation errors) the ModelState.IsValid will return false, in which case I need to return the same view.  See screenshot below!

[image]

Comment: Please post your Controller code where you validate and return the form.

Comment: are you implement javascript unsuportive validation so you can validate before doing postback

Comment: Why is KeyActiveMg defined as a nullable integer if it's required?

Comment: I changed the KeyActiveMg to non-nullable.  It doesn't matter if it's nullable or not, it still has the same problem.

Comment: @Trickery, I posted the controller code.

Comment: @MikeMarks Sorry just to clarify, You have problem only with client side validation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are returning another view (***Error***) if `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`. You should return the posted viewmodel to the same create view.

```
public ActionResult Create(RawValues model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     //everything is good. Lets save and redirect
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I'm just redirecting the user to an Error page that spits out the error onto the screen if Model.IsValid is false.

Comment: Why are you not returning to the same view ?

Comment: I can, but it has nothing to do with anything... I just added this in for debugging.  If model state is invalid, that's a problem that has nothing to do with the code I have INSIDE the ModelState.IsValid else statement.

Comment: @MikeMarks, no it has everything to do with it. The reason you're not seeing a validation error is because of what you're passing to your view. See my answer, I included full Controller code.

Comment: @Trickery I can't have two of the same Create methods with the same signatures because this results in a compile time error.

Comment: You missed the `HttpPost` attribute above one of them.

Comment: Thanks @Shyju, you had the most correct answer!  See my update.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not including 'jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js' and/or 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js'.  I believe these are required to interpret the metadata added by DataAnnotations and supply the validation methods your looking for.

Comment: Every other page I have validates though.  This is the only one that doesn't, and it's inheriting from a master page (as is the other pages that validate)

Answer (score 0):

When your model is invalid, you don't actually return it with it's validation errors. Then, you do this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KeyActiveMg)
```

but there is no Validation Message for anything. You returned a brand new view with a blank Model. Instead, you should return your invalid model to the view, like such:

```
return View(rawvalues);
```

**UPDATE**

Your controller should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new RawValues());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RawValues model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Your view seems fine, so it should work from here.

If you're talking about client side validation, you need to reference the necessary JS files. They should be already preconfigured in your Bundle config. You just need to add to your view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Just to make sure, your BundleConfig class that sits in the `App_Start` folder should have these:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Comment: But, it should never hit the [HttpPost] Create method before saying "Hey, you need to enter a value into Key Active Mg"

Comment: My bad, hasty copy pasting. Should be fine now. As for your validation, I suppose you're referring to client validation then. It won't save you if your server side validation is broken. You still need to return your invalid model back to the view. Anyway, for client validation, make sure you reference `jquery`, `jquery-ui` and `jquery.validate` in that order.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResultCreate(RawValues model)
{
 ....

 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 {
    ModelState.AddModelError("KeyActiveMg", "KeyActiveMg field is required");
    var model = new GetModel();
    return View("Results", model);
 }  

    rawvaluesRepository.InsertOrUpdate(rawvalues);
    rawvaluesRepository.Save();
    List<Results> results = Helpers.OperationContext.CallCalculate(rawvalues);
    return View("Results", results);
}
```

Comment: If the model is invalid you shouldn't have to manually add code to say what's required. Defeats the point of using data annotations.